# FXML file not being loaded

Tags: java, exception, javafx, fxml

So, I've got an FXML file, `BookView_FXML.fxml` and a controller `BookView`. The FXML file is loaded in a method `show()` inside the controller class. When I run the application I get an `fxml.LoadException`.

Here's the error report:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/path_to_package/memberApp/BookView_FXML.fxml:7

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:105)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:941)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at memberApp.BookView.display(BookView.java:58)
    at memberApp.HomeScreenController.lambda$initializeTableView$1(HomeScreenController.java:181)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3564)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8200(Scene.java:3492)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3860)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: memberApp.BookView
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:571)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:936)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: memberApp.BookView.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
    ... 45 more
```

The `BookView` class

```
package memberApp;

// excluded the import statements

public class BookView implements Initializable
{
    public AnchorPane root ;
    public Label bookIDLbl, titleLbl, authorLbl, isbnLbl, publisherLbl, categoryLbl, copiesAvailableLbl ;
    public VBox vbox ;

    private final Book theBook ;
    private String bookID, title, author, isbn, publisher, category, copiesAvailable ;

    public BookView(Book book)
    {
        this.theBook = book ;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle)
    {
        initializeData();
        initializeLabels() ;
    }


    public void display()
    {
        Stage primary_stage = new Stage() ;
        primary_stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL) ;   // the initModality specifies that the stage will block events
        primary_stage.setTitle("BOOK INFO") ;

        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("BookView_FXML.fxml"))) ;
            Scene scene = new Scene(root) ;

            primary_stage.setScene(scene) ;
            primary_stage.show() ;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("\nExceptions in BookView.display() -> " + e) ;
            e.printStackTrace() ;
        }
    }


    private void initializeData()
    {
        bookID = theBook.getBookID() ;
        title = theBook.getTitle() ;
        author = theBook.getAuthor() ;
        isbn = theBook.getIsbn() ;
        publisher = theBook.getPublisher() ;
        category = theBook.getCategory() ;
        copiesAvailable = theBook.getTotalCopies() ;
    }


    private void initializeLabels()
    {
        bookIDLbl.setText("BookID: " + bookID) ;
        titleLbl.setText(title) ;
        authorLbl.setText("BY " + author) ;
        isbnLbl.setText("ISBN: " + isbn) ;
        publisherLbl.setText("Publisher: " + publisher) ;
        categoryLbl.setText("Category: " + category) ;
        copiesAvailableLbl.setText("Copies Available: " + copiesAvailable) ;
    }
}
```

And the FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="root" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="650.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="memberApp.BookView">
   <Label fx:id="titleLbl" alignment="CENTER" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="50.0" text="&lt;title goes here&gt;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <font>
         <Font size="20.0" />
      </font>
   </Label>
   <Label fx:id="authorLbl" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" text="&lt;author's name goes here&gt;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0">
      <font>
         <Font size="15.0" />
      </font>
   </Label>
   <VBox fx:id="vbox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="250.0" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="10.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="100.0">
      <Label fx:id="bookIDLbl" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Label">
         <font>
            <Font size="13.5" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="isbnLbl" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Label">
         <font>
            <Font size="13.5" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="categoryLbl" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Label">
         <font>
            <Font size="13.5" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="publisherLbl" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Label">
         <font>
            <Font size="13.5" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="copiesAvailableLbl" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Label">
         <font>
            <Font size="13.5" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

I'm not sure what's causing the exception. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks but why would a parameterless constructor be needed? And ,if you don't mind, where exactly is this pointed out in the stack trace? And yeah I'll stick to the naming conventions. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: _java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: memberApp.BookView.<init>()_ .. as to the why - javadoc (here: of FxmlLoader) is your friend :)

Comment: What do you expect the `FXMLLoader` to pass to the constructor? If you want to finer control over how controllers are instantiated, consider either setting the controller manually on the `FXMLLoader`, or providing it with a `controllerFactory`.

Comment: Also consider the [custom component](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) FXML pattern, which perhaps is closer to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @kleopatra I added an empty constructor to the class and even changed the package name like you said. And now I get a `NullPointerException` at line 84 (i.e. ` bookIDLbl.setText("BookID: " + bookID) ;`). I don't understand how the label is identified as null.

Comment: @James_D What I'm trying to do is to open a window that displays some info about an item(a Book object), when double clicked, that's in a TableView (the TableView is in another class) . So I created a layout(BookView_FXML.fxml) and its respective constructor(BookView). The BookView class has a method called `show()` that loads the fxml file when called(shown above). The first problem I had was a `LoadException` and kleopatra suggested that I insert an empty constructor. Once I made this change the `LoadException` is not encountered but a `NullPointerException` is. I've mentioned it above.

Comment: @amateur-coder-1002 *“The `BookView` class has a method called `show()`…”*. This sounds like a design flaw. It’s not the responsibility of the controller to decide how the view is displayed - that should be done elsewhere. And note that you necessarily end up with two different `BookView` instances: the one on which `show()` is invoked, which has `theBook` initialised and all the `@FXML`-injected fields still null, and the one created by the FXML loader, which has `theBook` null and the `@FXML`-injected fields initialised.

Comment: @James_D yeah you're right - my design is wrong, I went through my code and updated it accordingly. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.